# Docker Desktop Backup

Tags: docker, kubernetes, backup, docker-desktop

I need advise, how to backup Docker/K8.

I am migrating my dev/lab environment from VMWare to Docker (which I am not 100% familiar yet) and I need to set up backup/restore procedure. It was quite simple with VMware images (copy all VM files).

I would like to backup "whole Docker desktop" or in other words, I nee to make lab environment recovery as simple as possible: e.g. "copy/untar backups to freshly installed PC" and after recovery all containers,defined networks, volumes, K8s, etc. are recovered as well. And after recovery procedure I am ready to start using "good old recovered containers".

I am aware that ideal scenario is to keep all container data in volumes and that there are defined procedures how to backup one by one:

- volumes ( https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#back-up-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes )
- images
- containers ( https://docs.docker.com/desktop/backup-and-restore/ )
- K8 backup/recovery is probably somehow defined ( I am not familiar yet ).

I am wondering if there is any way how to backup "Docker Desktop" as single "*tar*" file for example, because until I understand deeply Docker/K8 backup procedures, I would prefer to keep backup as simple as possible.

I am using Docker/WSL2 on Windows and my most "valuable" containers are 4+ Oracle Database containers ( with different Oracle versions/flavors), but I assume number containers will grow and I do not want to update backup script each time new container is created ( this would definitely end up in missed backup one day ).

I there any "simple" recommended way I missed ?

Comment: What in this setup can't be recreated from files that are checked into source control?  You should not need to back up containers (intrinsically temporary) or images (built from source and pushed to an external repository), nor Kubernetes manifests (checked into source control), and I wouldn't expect a developer environment to have valuable data in Docker volumes.

Comment: @David Maze I understand your point. But I do not agree, that volumes do not contain valuable data. Sure almost everything can be automated, but there are exceptions: for example Oracle Db image needs to be created by manual process . It requires running sh script and downloading manually install zip files because DockedHub does include "buggy image"), but I am trying to minimize my time consumed by tuning lab backup/restore procedure.

Comment: @David Maze You are right, that my lab Dbs does not include customer critical data, but it includes for example configuration data (for 3rd party old fashioned applications, which are still valuable for me, because configuration is tuned to match my development settings like `application.properties` or `appsettings.Development.json`). I am not and I do not aspire to be Oracle specialist, or Docker specialist and I am trying to figure out , how to backup "whole localhost" with minimum effort to backup/recover.

Comment: @David Maze To demonstrate it: I can spent time on learning how to map volumes to Oracle Docker to make sure that no data are not in Container itself ( and I agree that it is the recommended approach for production and I would love to do learn it, but it consumes time I cannot invest right now), but even without volumes I still would like to keep backups, because lab PC always tends to crash in least convenient time. And during the time I will tune up all Docker images ( to have data in volumes ).

Comment: @David, how do you backup your "Docker farm" volumes ? One by one by manually typing commands for each volume described here https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#back-up-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes ? It seems  time consuming to me. It might be feasible to backup \\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\volumes\ ? I have not tested it yet ...

Comment: _In a development environment_, there's nothing in particular to back up.  Tables can be recreated from migrations and seed data, plus imports of specific data.  It sounds like you might be asking about a less-temporary environment, and another site like [sf] or [devops] might be a more appropriate place to ask how to administer this system.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to build images of the existing containers that you are using, next docker save command can be used to save all your docker images but you need to mention each image name manually which you don’t want to do, however these docker commands can be executed by using python or shell script. This [document](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/images.html) explains clearly about how to manage your docker environment using python code. Refer this and there are many functions and example code snippets available, hope this will help you.